# Hayoo/Hoogle not matching monomorphic/less polymorphic signatures with polymorphic ones

Tags: haskell, types, hoogle, hayoo

I'm trying to understand if there's a fundamental reason for why Hoogle and Hayoo aren't matching, for instance

```hs
(b -> c) -> (b' -> c') ->   (b, b') -> (c, c')
```

to

```hs
a b c    -> a b' c'    ->   a (b, b') (c, c')
```

which happens to be the type of [`Control.Arrow.***`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-):

```hs
(***) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')
```

— is this likely just something that's as-of-yet unimplemented, or is there something fundamental that is preventing this sort of type based search from ever being implemented?

Comment: It matches if you use the prefix tuple constructor: `(,) b c -> (,) b' c' -> (,) (b, b') (c, c')`.

Comment: @C.Quilley: hold on... `b -> c` is not at all the same as `(,) b c` — so what do you mean? Your signature is of a function that takes 2 pairs and combines those into a pair of pairs.

Comment: ...and just for the record: even if what you meant was `((->) b c) -> ((->) b' c') -> ((->) (b, b') (c, c'))` — which is what I'm asking about — that still doesn't yield any results neither on Hayoo nor on Hoogle.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your post. I'm now as mystified as you are.

Answer (score 4):

With Hoogle, it seems to be a consequence of how `->` is handled. [Issue #64 in the GitHub tracker](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/issues/64), which is very similar to what we are discussing here, includes this comment by Neil Mitchell:

> Currently I quickly split out the result type from the arguments. I guess one approach would be to find instances for `->` and pregenerate a version with `->` substituted in.