# Function to automatically unwrap / rewrap values in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I made a function as follows:

```hs
pen :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
pen conv rev app = rev . app . conv
```

which is used as follows:

```hs
pen read show (\x -> x + 1) "5"
"6"
```

I am quite new to Haskell, and I am wondering if a function like this exists in the Haskell standard library and what it is called, as I can't find it on Hoogle.

I'm also assuming there is some way to achieve this without (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> ... and just having a single bijective function, but I'm also not sure how to do this.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, the parentheses around `read` and `show` are not needed. Your other question is off-topic, though.

Comment: You can just write `pen read show (\x -> x + 1)`. The space is used to call a function.

Comment: Ah that was just me being an idiot, I've edited the question to ask the main problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is [`Profunctor`ial `dimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#v:dimap), which is significant category-theoretically but isn't in the standard libraries.

Comment: @HTNW I think `dimap` is so good that it's worth making that an answer even though `profunctors` is third-party.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most standard name for a general version of this function is `dimap`.  It doesn't show up in a Hoogle search, unfortunately, since [Hoogle lacks support for instances involving `(->)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33234878/7509065).

Anyway, `dimap` is a type class method (for the `Profunctor` class), so it's more general than what you want (the same way `fmap` would be more general than what someone looking for `map` actually wants).  Specialized to the `Profunctor` instance for functions, it's **still** more general than you want, as it allows an arbitrary transformation of its input and output arguments to any types, so its type signature specialized to functions is:

```
dimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> d)
```

which can obviously be be further specialized to the function `pen` that you want:

```
dimap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> (a -> a)
```

It's not in `base`, but it's included in the `lens` package or in the standalone `profunctors` package:

```
> import Data.Profunctor   -- from "profunctors"
> dimap read show (\x -> x + 1) "5"
"6"
```

Haskell functions of type `a -> b` can't be "bijective" obviously, but if you use the `lens` package, an [`Iso`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) represents a bijective function.

You can define an `Iso` from a function and its inverse by writing:

```
> import Control.Lens
> showRead = iso show read
```

To apply a function using this `Iso` as a wrapper/unwrapper, you can use the Lens function [`under`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:under):

```
> under showRead (+1) "5"
"6"
```

I guess it's worth noting that `showRead` maybe isn't a great `Iso` (i.e., isn't fully law-abiding), since `show` and `read` aren't perfect inverses.  (That is, some `show` instances produce values that can't be `read` back to reproduce the value.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of Haskell is that it's easy to look up functions that you don't know the name of, just by their type. Put `(a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> a -> a` in [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) and try it. In this case, you get 4 hits, but they're all in third-party libraries. Two of them do exactly the same thing as your function, and two are almost the same but are more strict.

Also, note that your function has a type signature less general than it could, and all of the results have a more general one: `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> a -> d`. Using less general type signatures than you can is somewhat dangerous, as it allows mistakes that would otherwise be caught by the compiler. For example, `pen conv rev app = rev . conv` is wrong since it skips `app`. With your type signature, this would compile fine but you'd have a runtime bug. With the more general type signature, it would be a type error caught at compile time.

Comment: cool! is there a way I can also search for a bijective version of some sort that only takes one convertor function? sorry if im asking the wrong questions, im still learning (:

Comment: @insou How do you suppose the compiler would automatically know the inverse of an arbitrary function you'd give it?

Comment: ah, I thought there might be some kind of type for invertible functions where to satisfy the type you have to provide the inversion? possibly similar to proving a type is a monad? but I think I have no idea what im talking about :p

Comment: There might be something with `Iso` or something, but not in `base` and definitely not simple.